# How to change text color of dynamically created checkbox

Tags: android

I want to change the text color of dynamically created checkbox in android.

Please guide

Answer (score 9):

```
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox(this);
chk.setText("Testing");
chk.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

or From `color.xml`

```
chk.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

Comment: it will hide the text only check box apper

Answer (score 1):

This Code snippet may help ypu

```
CheckBox mCheckBox= new CheckBox(this);
mCheckBox.setTextColor(R.color.textcolor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i used to add `CheckBox` Dynamically to `RadioGroup`.

```
CheckBox mCheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
        //mCheckBox.setText(String.format("%s",header));
        //mCheckBox.setId(index1);
        //mCheckBox.setLayoutParams(lp);
      //    mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        //mCheckBox.setPadding(mCheckBox.getTotalPaddingLeft() + 10, 0, 0, 10);
        mCheckBox.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

in above code you can see how CheckBox Text Color is set and also you can refer it by it's id.

Comment: my checkbox are in for loop like for (k = 0; k < strwsite.size(); k++) {
      Strwebsitename = strwsite.get(k);
      chkbx[k] = new CheckBox(this);
      chkbx[k].setText(Strwebsitename);
      chkbx[k].setTextColor(color.black);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change text color for checkbox you need to do it last thing, after methods like: setText(), setListener...

```
try {
    mCheckBox.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red, null));
} catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

Some old APIs will trigger NoSuchMethodError exception so it will be good to catch it. And don't forget to set your theme or go with null if so.